# Make a histogram from a table

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I have this  table I created with the function `table()`, I would like to make a histogram for example, the first group of bars shows El CARMEN and the correspond numbers of Urbana and Vereda that it has. I am using **R**.

```
sexo     EL CARMEN EL RETIRO GUARNE LA CEJA LA UNION MARINILLA RIONEGRO SN VICENTE
  Urbana        10        20      6      20       14        13       10         12
  Vereda         6         0      7       1        7         1        5         19
```

Comment: Recommend specifying the language you're working in.

Comment: A histogram is made from continuous or ordinal data, not already-summarized data, and not (I believe) form categorical data like this. What I think you need is done with `barplot(sexo)` (or whatever the variable name is holding the table).